# How to send a "Custom E-mail" when a data validation dropdown value is selected

Tags: validation, email, google-sheets, conditional-statements, notifications

Right now, when a person selects a certain value in the dropdown in Sheets, it sends a generic e-mail with limited information.  Is there a way for us to customize this e-mail to contain more useful information?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhRHM.png)

I entered the value in the dropdown, I received this standard e-mail, I wanted more useful information in the e-mail

Comment: Sure there is a way to do this.  There is not much to go off of without getting any specifics, however.  Exactly what information do you want to include? It would also help to see your current script and a screenshot showing the layout of your spreadsheet.